# onDraw not getting called for a custom view derived from view in layout

Tags: android

I have a custom view
.........

```
package com.yasir.canvasTest;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class GraphView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = "GraphView";
    public static boolean BAR = true;
    public static boolean LINE = false;

    private Paint paint;
    private float[] values;
    private String[] horlabels;
    private String[] verlabels;
    private String title;
    private boolean type;
    public Canvas tmpCanvas = null;

    public GraphView(Context context, float[] values, String title, String[] horlabels, String[] verlabels) {
        super(context);
        //setScrollContainer(true);
        Log.v(TAG,"On GraphView==>");




        paint = new Paint();

        setWillNotDraw(false);
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {




        Log.v(TAG,"<==On Draw");

/// drawing code here
        invalidate();
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Log.v(TAG,"On onMeasure==>");
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(
                parentWidth * 2, parentHeight);
    }

}
```

...............
Activity: onCreate
...............

```
setContentView(R.layout.horscroll);

HorizontalScrollView hsView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hzsv);

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearParent);
ll.removeAllViews();


// create custom view and add to laywout
GraphView graphView = new GraphView(this, values, "GraphViewDemo",horlabels, verlabels, GraphView.LINE);


hsView.requestLayout();
hsView.setWillNotDraw(false);

ll.requestLayout();
ll.setWillNotDraw(false);
ll.addView(graphView);
```

.....................
Xml
....................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<HorizontalScrollView
 android:id="@+id/hzsv"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearParent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

..................

Regards,
Yasir Perwez

Answer (score 4):

Try checking with **Hierarchy Viewer** what's going on. I suspect your view is not getting drawn because it has a 0 width, and this could be for two reasons (either or both):

- you're not setting any `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` on your custom view before adding it to the layout, and I'm not sure if the default ones are of the "fill parent" kind;
- your `onMeasure()` is incomplete, it should take into account also the mode (`UNSPECIFIED`, `EXACTLY`, `AT_MOST`) wich will depend from the layout params too. There's no guarantee that `getSize()` returns parent's size, and as the framework is meant, you shouldn't even know if that happens.

(@slund's suggestion will probably be useful too)

Comment: good point about the layout params.  I realize I did add layoutparams in my test, so I went back and tested without as well.  Either way I was getting asked to measure at zero width.  This actually puzzles me.  I even put the scrollview into a linear layout with "fill_parent" width and STILL get measured at zero.  I need to dig into this more.  fillViewport does help in any case, but I'm just not satisfied yet. Clearly I have more to learn on scrollviews :-)

Comment: @slund: docs say that `onMeasure()` might get called several times, even with 0-0 sizes, to see what size the view would like to be. See [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), section Layout.

Comment: Ok. Back from reading the code and I now understand what is happening.  HorizontalScrollView overrides measureChild and measureChildWithMargins and forces the width MeasureSpec to MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED.  If you set fillViewport to true, child.measure is called directly with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY and width of the viewport. Thus, any view in a HorizontalScrollView MUST handle MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED type in their onMeasure and determine their own width.  No matter what you put in the XML for layout_width.

Answer (score 1):

Your GraphView is getting measured with a width of 0 (zero).  You are then requesting that it be set to 2*width, which is still zero.  The draw logic will optimize not asking a zero width view to draw.

Probably what you want is to ask the HorizontalScrollView to fill the full width of the view with android:fillViewport="true", ie:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hzsv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearParent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

ALso see @bigstones answer.  You really need to handle all MeasureSpec types (UNSPECIFIED, AT_MOST, EXACTLY).  Setting fillViewport="true" gets your onMeasure called with type EXACTLY and the width of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks all for such a good support it was very helpfull. got my issued solved. and learned things about scrollviews