# post invalidate() works in lollipop but not on marshmallow

Tags: android, android-animation, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to animate a continuous sine graph with the following code inside onDraw() method of a custom GraphView class:

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() - prevTime >= 10)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        //Looping through the sine values
            newsine[i] = values[(i+1)%(values.length)];

        }
       //This will assign newsine array back to values array
        setValues(newsine);
        Log.d("LOG_TAG",""+newsine[0]);
        prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        postInvalidate();
    }
```

This works fine in Lollipop but doesn't work on marshmallow(6.0 and 6.1), onDraw isn't called after 3 or 4 times.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should call `invalidate();`

Comment: invalidate() also gives the same result... :(

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804919/ondraw-not-getting-called-for-a-custom-view-derived-from-view-in-layout ?

Comment: I think in that case onDraw() isn't getting called at all... In my case it works for a while and then stops